# Firebase "no auth token for request" Error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download a file from Firebase. I've done all the requirements to set up the cloud Storage from Firebase and made my cloud storage open :

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

I have a single `materialButton` that, when clicked, should download the file from the cloud storage and store it in the Download Directory. Here's my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    MaterialButton mconvertButton;
    FirebaseStorage mfirebaseStorage;
    StorageReference mstorageReference;
    StorageReference ref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mconvertButton = findViewById(R.id.convertButton);
        mconvertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                download();
            }
        });

    }
    public void download(){
        mstorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        ref = mstorageReference.child("_HDbN_ugHkQ.wav");
        ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                String url = uri.toString();
                downloadFiles(MainActivity.this, "_HDbN_ugHkQ",
                        ".wav", DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, url);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    public void downloadFiles(Context context, String fileName, String fileExtension, String destinationDirectory, String url){
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.
                getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, destinationDirectory, fileName + fileExtension);

    }
```

However, everytime I click the button, I get back :

```
W/StorageUtil: no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest: no auth token for request
```

I've tried to clean my app data, I've tried to uninstall and reinstall my app. I checked multiple time that my app was still connected to firebase but the problem remains. 
Do you have any ideas on how to solve this ?

**Log Details**

Comment: The "W" in front of those log lines is telling you those are warnings, not errors.  You should instead look for the results of the operation that get delivered on the failure listener.  That exception will tell you what went wrong.  Please edit the question with the details in that exception.  `Log.e("TAG", "error", e);`

Comment: I did just what you said but nothing is being shown in the logcat, even with filters on.

Comment: I added `Log.e("TAG", "error", e);` in the `public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)` and I have nothing written in the logcat. I created a custom filter with `LogTag : "TAG"` and `LogMessage : "error"`but still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I forgot to add `downloadManager.enqueue(request);` to my `downloadFiles` function.